# cant login website using httpwebrequest/responce vb.net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am a newb to vb.net(visual studio 2008).i am trying to make an app using vb.net which can be used to login to a website and browse that website without using webbrowser(i dont want to use webbrowser of vb.net).i got a code for this from net ;I have made a temporary login webpage using php and mysql in my computer(its working properly).
but when i tried to login using vb.net its not working...
because i dont know in which part of the code is not working,i am pasting the whole code here.

below is my html code for login form

```
    <td style="width: 188px;"><input maxlength="120" size="30" name="login" class="css"  id="login"><br>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td><b>Password</b></td>
<td><input maxlength="100" size="30" name="password" class="css" id="password" type="password"><br>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="submit" value="Login" class="button" type="submit"></td>
```

this is the vb.net code that i got it from net.i changed the url to my localhost website..and added username and password(both root) and also this `<big>Welcome`

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cookieJar As New Net.CookieContainer()
        Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse
        Dim strURL As String

        Try
            'Get Cookies
            strURL = "http://localhost/login.php"
            request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
            request.Method = "GET"
            request.CookieContainer = cookieJar
            response = request.GetResponse()

            For Each tempCookie As Net.Cookie In response.Cookies
                cookieJar.Add(tempCookie)
            Next

            'Send the post data now
            request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
            request.CookieContainer = cookieJar

            Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
            writer.Write("login=root & password=root")
            writer.Close()
            response = request.GetResponse()

            'Get the data from the page
            Dim stream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim data As String = stream.ReadToEnd()
            RichTextBox1.Text = data
            WebBrowser1.DocumentText = RichTextBox1.Text
            response.Close()

            If data.Contains("<big>Welcome") = True Then
                'LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method just works for websites which use URL parameter. Make sure you can login to your site like this:

```
http://localhost/login.php?user=your_username&password=your_password
```

Also remove spaces here:

```
writer.Write("login=root&password=root")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are sending correct `HttpWebRequest`

you can use [Live HTTP Headers plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to capture web request/response.

First install either of above and then log-in to the site using your web browser and capture 'requested data' from your web browser.

Then create your `HttpWebRequest` according to that data.

if your site uses 'HTTP GET' method then use Alex85's method.

`http://localhost/login.php?user=your_username&password=your_password`

you can try following code for 'HTTP POST' method.

```
 Dim Request As HttpWebRequest
 Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse
 Dim cookieJar As New Net.CookieContainer()

 Dim strURL As String = "http://localhost/login.php"
 dim PostData as string
 PostData = "login=root&password=root" 'Set this according to captured data

 request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
 Request.Host = "localhost"
 request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
 request.Method = "GET"
 request.CookieContainer = cookieJar
 response = request.GetResponse()

 For Each tempCookie As Net.Cookie In response.Cookies
      cookieJar.Add(tempCookie)
 Next

Response.Close()

    Request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
    Request.Host = "localhost"
    Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1"
    Request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    Request.KeepAlive = True
    Request.CookieContainer = CookieJar
    Request.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Request.Method = "POST"
    Request.ContentLength = PostData.Length

    Dim requestStream As Stream = Request.GetRequestStream()
    Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData)

    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
    Dim stream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim data As String = stream.ReadToEnd()
    RichTextBox1.Text = data
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = RichTextBox1.Text
    response.Close()

        If data.Contains("<big>Welcome") = True Then
            'LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY
        End If
```